# font does not support any style like 'regular' 'bold' 'Italic'

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, styles

how can i work with font that dose not support any kind of FontStyle. by the way, I can not create a font Object from it. help??

Comment: It's hard to help you if you don't provide any information to work with. What font are you talking about? What platform? What technology are you using to create a "font Object", what calls on that platform? What do you ultimately wish to accomplish?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i use C# and develop winform app. i can not create fontObject like this:   Font myFont = new Font(family.Name, 12, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point); font that i use if Persian font.

Comment: some of this font are persian font but some other are latin font and all of them are True Type. like below fonts:   "Brush Script MT.ttf"-
"Harlow Solid Italic.ttf"-
"Monotype Corsiva.ttf"-
"Palace Script MT.ttf"-
"Vivaldi.ttf"

Comment: These are decorative fonts, meant for headlines and titles.  They have only one FontStyle, Italic for the ones you mention.

Answer (score 5):

The font code on Windows (as on any platform I guess) doesn't create new fonts from scratch; it will rather interpret what fonts are installed / available on your system and give you a way to work with those.

Each font is reached by making a FontFamily object; such a FontFamily then contains Font objects for each style that is available. If a certain style (such as 'bold' or 'italic') is not available on your system, you won't be able to create it.

You can test whether this is the case by using the FontFamily.IsStyleAvailable. Defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontfamily.isstyleavailable.aspx) as:

```
public bool IsStyleAvailable(
    FontStyle style
)
```

If you want to create a font, you'll have to make sure it's available on the system first (which means you'll have to use a common font or package the font with your solution if you want an uncommon one).