# Strange exception "does not support style 'regular'" on GDI+

Tags: .net, fonts, gdi+

I'm running some tests about font on Windows8.1 x64 using .NET framework 4.0. Then the problem comes out...

After installed about 1000-1500 fonts in system, I using the following code try to get all fonts and to test their render size.

```cs
static void Test3()
{
    var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(500, 500, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    foreach (var f in FontFamily.Families)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Write("test [" + f.Name + "] ...");

            var fn = new System.Drawing.Font(f, 16.0f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
            g.MeasureString("test TEST 测试 测试測試 測試 繁體 簡體 楷體 繁体 简体 楷体", fn);
            Console.WriteLine("[OK]");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[ERR] " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

But sadly, this piece of code can't run normally. It will show many many ERR like this:

[image: ERROR SHOWN]

Notice the row with red border. It said Font '黑体' does not support style 'Regular'.

And now consider the follow codes:

```
static void Test2()
{
    var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(500, 500, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    foreach (var f in FontFamily.Families.Where(s => s.Name == "黑体"))
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Write("test [" + f.Name + "] ...");

            var fn = new System.Drawing.Font(f, 16.0f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
            g.MeasureString("test TEST 测试 测试測試 測試 繁體 簡體 楷體 繁体 简体 楷体", fn);
            Console.WriteLine("[OK]");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[ERR] " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

It just ignore all other fonts but only test '黑体'. And here's the result:

[image: ....]

....and now I'm fully confused. Could anybody explain why ?
Thanks.

## [UPDATED] Here's More investigation

Consider these code snippets:

[Code1]

```
var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(500, 500, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
var fam = FontFamily.Families;
var dic1 = fam.ToDictionary(s => s.Name, s => s.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular));
Console.WriteLine(dic1.Values.Count(s => s));
```

[Code2]

```
var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(500, 500, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
var fam = FontFamily.Families;
var dic2 = fam.ToDictionary(s => s.Name, s =>
{
    var b = s.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular);

    if (b)
    {
        var fn = new System.Drawing.Font(s, 16.0f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
        try
        {
            g.MeasureString(s.Name, fn);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Name + " -> Failed -> " + ex.Message);
        }
        fn.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Name + " -> NOT SUPPORT.");
    }
    return b;
});

Console.WriteLine(dic2.Values.Count(s => s));
```

They are both to calculate the fonts that supports Regular. The only difference was in the second code snippet, we use MesureString to test a string if it support Regular.

But  run them spearatly, You will notice the result really different....

[image: two results]

(note the result second was from code1)

Then I really want to ask : why some fonts reported SUPPORT regular in  code1 but NOT SUPPORT regular in code2?...

Comment: It happens, I've seen an example of an oblique font that didn't implement the Regular style, only Italic.  It's rare, but if you let this code loose on 1500 fonts then you're liable to find one :)  The font mapper normally provides a substitute, pretty unclear why it does in one case but not the other.  A memory problem would be a wild guess, these are *not* small fonts.  Be wary of freeware fonts, pirated versions of SimHei are all over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Did the same fonts work before? I remember an acquaintance running into something similar and the exception was thrown because fonts did not support specific styles. 
You can also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671981/font-does-not-support-any-style-like-regular-bold-italic), it explains your issue a more technical way.

Comment: This font works well. The problem was why this font style **SUPPORT** regular at first but **NOT** **SUPPORT** regular in the next piece of code. In this question, **f.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular)** will return **TRUE** in **Test3()** but **FALSE** in Test2().

Comment: uhhm....I assume 's' is hard coded location font, huh? test2 might be working because you are using 's' and not 'f' in loop definition. also.
try running test2 with FontFamily.Families.Where(f.IsStyleAvailable.Regular)

Comment: No error, but many fonts disappeared. The fonts disappeared could be used standalone without any issue..